# Is it true that it is common for programs written in C to contain assembly code?

Tags: c

I have read [this](http://www.linfo.org/source_code.html), saying that

> For example, it is common for programs that are written primarily in C to contain portions that are in an assembly language for optimization of processor efficiency.

I have never seen a program written primarily in C that contains assembly code too, at least not directly as source code. Only, their example with the Linux kernel.

Is this statement true and if so, how could it possibly optimize processor efficiency?

Aren't C code just *translated* into assembly code by the compiler?

Comment: That may have been true, but for user-space programs its becoming rare(r). Compilers are quite good at optimizing the generated assembly (or other intermediate representation) nowadays

Comment: How could it possibly *not* optimize the code to write code directly to the processor rather than being translated from an abstract representation? It's pretty rare these days, but there are still places where one instruction matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true. I'd estimate that less than 1% of C programmers even know how to program in assembly, and the need to use it is very rare. It's generally only needed for very special applications, such as some parts of an OS kernel or programming embedded systems, because they need to perform machine operations that don't have corresponding C code (such as directly manipulating CPU registers). In earlier days some programmers would use it for performance-critical sections of code, but compiler optimizations have improved significantly, and CPUs have gotten faster, so this is rarely needed now. It might still be used in the built-in libraries, so that functions like `strcpy()` will be as fast as possible. But application programmers almost never have to resort to assembly.

Comment: Wow thank you! Thanks for clearing that up! But based on what you wrote and what "Lee Daniel Crocker" wrote as comment to the op, I can see how assembly code in your source code could help access certain things that c code might can't.  But Lee made it sound like assembly code would save number of instructions and thereby make code more efficient, but isn't it very possible to also make slow assembly code and thus not save any instructions and not make code more efficient, just as it is when using c code? So isn't it wrong to say that assembly code is used to save Instructions?

Comment: Of course, you can write bad code in any language. The point is that assembly has the *potential* to save instructions, because you have direct control over the instructions that are used. So if the C compiler produces inefficient code, a good assembly programmer can do better.

Comment: Ahh cool. What a response time :-) one final question then: you mention that built-in libraries could use assembly code, but since assembly language is architecture specific, did the programmers of those libraries make different code for each architecture /processor? :-/

Comment: Yes, they do it either with preprocessor conditionals, or by linking in different versions of a file from architecture-specific directories.

Comment: But aren't there many different processors out there,so doesnr it take very much time to write different code for each processor?? Like if there are more than 1000, they have to write 1000 different versions of the code and know each processor!?

Comment: There aren't that many different architectures in common use. x86, SPARC, ARM. And they probably only bother with this for the most common ones, and fall back to generic C code for the rest.

Comment: Great, I'll mark your answer as the answer in a moment, but in the meantime, can you also answer the comment to John's answer below? Not that I expect you to, but it would be cool, because then I might did not have to wait that long :))) I am not the most patient guy

Answer (score 0):

> Aren't C code just translated into assembly code by the compiler?

Yes, but...

There are situations where you may want to access a specific register or other platform-specific location, and Standard C doesn't provide good ways to do that.  If you want to look at a status word or load/read a data register *directly*, then you often need to drop down to the assembler level.

Also, even in this age of very smart optimizing compilers, it's still possible for a human assembly programmer to write assembly code that will out-perform code generated by the compiler.  If you need to wring every possible cycle out of your code, you may need to "go manual" for a couple of routines.

Comment: Alright, neat! Thanks! But is this also applicable to c++?

Comment: There's nothing special about C. This is true for any language.

Comment: The question was whether it's *common*, not whether it's ever necessary.

Comment: @Barmar "There's nothing special about C. This is true for any language" - Maybe I should have been clearer: I was wondering if it is also true for C++ that you can add assembly code manually when you want to access a specific register, and that the Standard C++ library does not provide good ways to do this, just as for C?

Comment: @sdsadasdasd The ability to use assembly in C programs is not part of the standard, it's a common compiler extension. And it's the same extension in C++ compilers. And in general, one of the main purposes of high level languages is to abstract away hardware details like registers, they don't provide any standard way to access them directly.